# Failed First Answer audit by upvoting and choosing "Other action"

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits, first-answers

I was reviewing a particular First Answer in the queue. It was an audit and I failed.

It is strange that I failed because I up-voted the answer and selected "Other action" and submitted. The answer was actually helpful and I thought up-voting it was appropriate.

Here is the review link: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/30408401

Is this a system problem or my mistake?

Comment: Apparently, you’re supposed to choose Looks OK: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371701/unable-to-pass-first-question-first-answer-review-audits

Comment: Hey @BSMP thanks for commenting. I read all of chained posts from duplicate flag to yours. But I also see that people get confused why is it not clear that upvoting good question as audit review is wrong.

Comment: @Mario yeah well, status-review. It's probably still a bug.